# Git flow workflow - hotfix conflicts with branch permissions

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, pull-request, git-flow

I have a question that I feel like would be a common issue for many people. However, I'm unable to find any answer to my question.

I have a bitbucket repository that is using the git flow workflow (not using git-flow). However, I'm currently experiencing some workflow issues when using branch permissions. I have the following branch naming convention:

- `master`
- `develop`
- `hotfix/...`
- `release/...`
- `feature/...`

I have configured my repository with write access, on branches `master` and `develop`, only through pull requests. For all other branches full permission is given, i.e. anyone can push code to them.

The problem I have can be explained by the following sequence of actions.

1. A release was made a while ago. It got merged into `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.
2. Development continues; `feature` branches is created and merged into `origin/develop` through pull requests.
3. A critical bug is identified in the live code (`origin/master`).
4. A `hotfix` branch is created from `master`, let's call it `hotfix/some-hotfix`.
5. The bug is fixed and `hotfix/some-hotfix` branch is pushed to the repository. We now also have a remote branch `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix`. At this stage we have:

   - `origin/develop` is a head of `origin/master` by a number of commits (depends on how development has progressed).
   - `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix` is a head of master (by the commits made to fix the bug).
6. A pull request is created to merge `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix` into `origin/master`. This will work fine, since `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix` is created from `origin/master`.

**Note:** The pull request is not necessarily resolved, i.e. `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix` is not merged into `origin/master`.

7. A pull request is created to merge `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix` into `origin/develop`. This will, in many cases, results in conflicts; changes have been made to both branches.

I can't merge `origin/develop` into `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix`, since this branch is intended to me merged into `origin/master`. Any changes pushed to the hotfix branch, before a finalised pull request to master, will also end up in master. Changes made to develop might break master.

One solution is that, I can be very careful and make sure that any pull requests to master is completed before starting to process the pull requests to develop. In my opinion, this is not ideal. This is both risky (what if I forget) and hinders further development (no one can start to go through the pull request from hotfix to develop before master is done):

I feel like this would be a common problem with this workflow.

## Questsion

Based on the above

1. Am I interpreting the git flow workflow in the wrong way?
2. How do you guys do it?
3. How can i solve the problem, or avoid it altogether?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not interpreting the workflow in a wrong way.

I think we can have this `hotfix/some-hotfix` branch to be merged in master. After that, we can merge the master branch into `origin/develop` to get the latest code of `master` branch into it, or we can rebase the `origin/develop` branch with `master`. I think it's better to merge. You will have to resolve conflicts in `develop` branch after merging/rebasing the `master`

Comment: Okay, if I understand you correctly, I will push my local `hotfix/some-hotfix` to the remote `origin/hotfix/some-hotfix`. Then, I will create a pull request to merge the remote branch `origin/hotfix/some-hotifx` into the remote branch `origin/master`, approve the pull request (merge it). I pull  the latest changes from the remote branches `origin/master` and `origin/develop`. I can then merge `master` into `develop`. However, I don't have permission to push `develop`. I have to create a pull request. But, how can I do that from my local branch `develop` into my remote branch `origin/develop`?

Comment: Is there a way to make a pull request from my local branch `develop` into my remote branch `origin/develop`?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to have a PR with the same base branch. One thing that you can do is create a branch from `develop`, merge `master` into that branch and make a PR to be merged in `develop` with this newly created branch. Take a pull after merging that newly created branch.